# On how to update AutoEncoder generated image when learning GAN using AutoEncoder

Tags: python, numpy, keras, autoencoder, generative-adversarial-network

The contents of main ()
When updating the generator
'''
noise = np.array (size = [batch_size, batch_images], low = -1.0, high = 1.0)
'''
Since I am using np.array, I get an error and what should I assign to this part

During the standard GAN
I used the following when renewing the generator but the place I changed to the code above did not train
'''
noise = np.random.uniform (size = [batch_size, batch_images], low = -1.0, high = 1.0)
'''

We are making GAN using Autoencoder.
Originally it is basically to let the generator generate images using random numbers, but in my GAN we learn to compete with discriminator using a generator that outputs the same as input like Autoencoder I think that I think that the generator has weights and weights common to the input image as we do learning.
Although I am a beginner who started Deep leaning yet, I can implement standard GAN, but I can not implement the above-mentioned GAN

I think that there is something wrong with the code of the part of main () which is doing learning, but if there is a person who understands please give me a professor

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Reshape
from keras.layers.core import Activation
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.convolutional import UpSampling2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU
from keras.layers.core import Flatten,Dropout
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import os
import glob
import random

n_colors = 3

def generator_model():
    model = Sequential()
    #encode
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (5, 5),input_shape=(64, 64, n_colors),activation='relu', padding='same'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))

    model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5),activation='relu', padding='same'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))

    model.add(Conv2D(16, (5, 5),activation='relu', padding='same'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))
    #decode
    model.add(Conv2D(16,(5,5),activation='relu',padding='same'))
    model.add(UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(32,(5,5),activation='relu',padding='same'))
    model.add(UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(64,(5,5),activation='relu'))
    model.add(UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(n_colors,(5,5),activation='sigmoid', border_mode='same'))
    return model

def discriminator_model():
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(64(5,5),
input_shape(64,64,n_colors),padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(128, (5, 5)))
    model.add(Activation('tanh'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Flatten())

    model.add(Dense(1024))
    model.add(Activation('tanh'))

    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
    return model

def generator_containing_discriminator(generator, discriminator):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(generator)
    model.add(discriminator)
    return model

def image_batch(batch_size):
    files = glob.glob("./in_images/**/*.jpg", recursive=True)
    files = random.sample(files, batch_size)
    # print(files)
    res = []
    for path in files:
        img = Image.open(path)
        img = img.resize((64, 64))
        arr = np.array(img)
        arr = (arr - 127.5) / 127.5
        arr.resize((64, 64, n_colors))
        res.append(arr)
    return np.array(res)

def combine_images(generated_images, cols=5, rows=5):
    shape = generated_images.shape
    h = shape[1]
    w = shape[2]
    image = np.zeros((rows * h,  cols * w, n_colors))
    for index, img in enumerate(generated_images):
        if index >= cols * rows:
            break
        i = index // cols
        j = index % cols
        image[i*h:(i+1)*h, j*w:(j+1)*w, :] = img[:, :, :]
    image = image * 127.5 + 127.5
    image = Image.fromarray(image.astype(np.uint8))
    return image

def set_trainable(model, trainable):
    model.trainable = trainable
    for layer in model.layers:
        layer.trainable = trainable

def main():
    batch_size = 55

    discriminator = discriminator_model()
    generator = generator_model()

    discriminator_on_generator = generator_containing_discriminator(generator, discriminator)

    set_trainable(discriminator, False)
    discriminator_on_generator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0002, beta_1=0.5))

    print(generator.summary())
    print(discriminator_on_generator.summary())

    set_trainable(discriminator, True)
    discriminator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0002, beta_1=0.5))

    print(discriminator.summary())

    for i in range(30 * 1000):
        batch_images = image_batch(batch_size)

      　#generator update
        #noise = np.random.uniform(size=[batch_size, batch_images], low=-1.0, high=1.0)
        noise = np.array(size=[batch_size, batch_images], low=-1.0, high=1.0)

        generated_images = generator.predict(image_batch)

        # discriminator update
        X = np.concatenate((batch_images, generated_images))
        # Learn so that the label of the training data becomes 1 and the 
        # label of the generated image becomes 0
        y = [1] * batch_size + [0] * batch_size
        d_loss = discriminator.train_on_batch(X, y)

        # generator update
        noise = np.array(size=[batch_size, batch_images], low=-1.0, high=1.0)

        # When I put the generated image in the discriminator
        # Learn so that the output becomes close to 1 
        #(the probability of being identified 
        # as a training image increases)
        g_loss = discriminator_on_generator.train_on_batch(noise, [1] * batch_size)

        if i % 100 == 0:
            print("step %d d_loss, g_loss : %g %g" % (i, d_loss, g_loss))
            image = combine_images(generated_images)
            os.system('mkdir -p ./generate_images')
            image.save("./gen_images/gen%05d.jpg" % i)
            generator.save_weights('generator.h5', True)
            discriminator.save_weights('discriminator.h5', True)

main()
```

Learning starts normally, some sort of image is generated and it should be displayed as follows
step 0 d_loss, g_loss : 0.675611 0.594226

However, the following error occurs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "keras_dcgan_copy.py", line 213, in <module>
    main()
  File "keras_dcgan_copy.py", line 188, in main
    noise = np.array(size=[batch_size, batch_images], low=-1.0, high=1.0)
TypeError: Required argument 'object' (pos 1) not found
```

Comment: `np.array` needs a first argument, which is the data it should convert into an array. You aren't passing it anything. I believe you meant to use `numpy.random.normal` or some other stochastic noise generator.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the following line. The noise should be randomly distributed numpy array.

```
noise = np.array(size=[batch_size, batch_images], low=-1.0, high=1.0)
```

You may change the above line to the following. And also `batch_images` is not a size. It's a numpy array of images. So instead of `batch_images`, you should give the shape of the output of the generator here. For an example, if generator outputs `(64,64,3)` colour image, you must give this in place of batch_images.

```
noise = np.random.uniform(size=[batch_size, gen_out_xshape, gen_out_yshape, no_of_channels], low=-1.0, high=1.0)
```

Note that `no_of_channels` is not needed if the images are in the grayscale format.